# How to get the total length from two array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i dont know how to compose my question, im working on a test project on CRM dynamics and my goal is i want to get all of the sent emails and this is my code:

```
personEmails.forEach(function(test) {
  var b = test.IncidentId;
  var $sentEmails = cbs.CaseDocuments.getSentEmails(personId, b);
  $.when($sentEmails).then(function(sentEmails) {
    test = sentEmails.length;
    return test++;
  });
});
```

on the `personEmails` i get the `incidentId` to get the list of sent emails on the `getSentEmails` and on the first loop there are two emails sent which is an another set of an array and on the second loop there was only one email sent and i got only two result and on the first loop it counts only as 1 instead of two. can anyone help me with my code to get the total emails sent. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you might want to add that in your tag so people can help you better.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add jquery on the tag :) thanks for the comment

Comment: It's not clear what you're intending here. You're using promises, so this code runs asynchronously. Where are you expecting the lengths to go to?

Comment: `return test++` returns the old value of `test`, not the incremented value, because you're using post-increment rather than pre-increment. Just use `return test + 1`

Comment: i want put all of the length on the test++ to add that result on the notification on the CRM

Comment: ok sir i'll try that. thank you so much for the help, im just studying now the javascript. thanks for the understanding